# Creating a monthly calendar in each spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

Now I finally managed to get all the code together, and now everything looks correct and does not give any syntax error. However, after the code is completed, the program does not do anything at all.

I have an application in VBA that asks for the start date (month) and for the end date, and then it outputs the monthly calendar with each month in each spreadsheet.

For example: If the user selects September (8) as the start date and December as the end date (11) it should output all the months between September and December in each spreadsheet.

Here is the code for this

```
   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    start_date.AddItem ("January"), 0
    start_date.AddItem ("February"), 1
    start_date.AddItem ("March"), 2
    start_date.AddItem ("April"), 3
    start_date.AddItem ("May"), 4
    start_date.AddItem ("June"), 5
    start_date.AddItem ("July"), 6
    start_date.AddItem ("August"), 7
    start_date.AddItem ("September"), 8
    start_date.AddItem ("October"), 9
    start_date.AddItem ("November"), 10
    start_date.AddItem ("December"), 11


    end_date.AddItem ("January"), 0
    end_date.AddItem ("February"), 1
    end_date.AddItem ("March"), 2
    end_date.AddItem ("April"), 3
    end_date.AddItem ("May"), 4
    end_date.AddItem ("June"), 5
    end_date.AddItem ("July"), 6
    end_date.AddItem ("August"), 7
    end_date.AddItem ("September"), 8
    end_date.AddItem ("October"), 9
    end_date.AddItem ("November"), 10
    end_date.AddItem ("December"), 11

End Sub


Private Sub newProjectNext1_Click()
    Dim strArrayOne(11) As String
    Dim wsArrayOne(11) As Worksheet

    strArrayOne(0) = "January"
    strArrayOne(1) = "February"
    strArrayOne(2) = "March"
    strArrayOne(3) = "April"
    strArrayOne(4) = "May"
    strArrayOne(5) = "June"
    strArrayOne(6) = "July"
    strArrayOne(7) = "August"
    strArrayOne(8) = "September"
    strArrayOne(9) = "October"
    strArrayOne(10) = "November"
    strArrayOne(11) = "December"

    Dim ArrayTwo(11) As String
    ArrayTwo(0) = "January 2015"
    ArrayTwo(1) = "February 2015"
    ArrayTwo(2) = "March 2015"
    ArrayTwo(3) = "April 2015"
    ArrayTwo(4) = "May 2015"
    ArrayTwo(5) = "June 2015"
    ArrayTwo(6) = "July 2015"
    ArrayTwo(7) = "August 2015"
    ArrayTwo(8) = "September 2015"
    ArrayTwo(9) = "October 2015"
    ArrayTwo(10) = "November 2015"
    ArrayTwo(11) = "December 2015"

    Do Until start_date.ListIndex <= end_date.ListIndex
        Set wsArrayOne(start_date.ListIndex) = Sheets.Add
        Sheets.Add.Name = strArrayOne(start_date.ListIndex)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Range("a1:g14").Clear
        MyInput = ArrayTwo(start_date.ListIndex)
        If MyInput = "" Then Exit Sub
        StartDay = DateValue(MyInput)
        If Day(StartDay) <> 1 Then
            StartDay = DateValue(Month(StartDay) & "/1/" & _
                                 Year(StartDay))
        End If
        Range("a1").NumberFormat = ArrayTwo(start_date.ListIndex)
        With Range("a1:g1")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Font.Size = 18
            .Font.Bold = True
            .RowHeight = 35
        End With
        With Range("a2:g2")
            .ColumnWidth = 11
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Orientation = xlHorizontal
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Font.Bold = True
            .RowHeight = 20
        End With
        Range("a2") = "Sunday"
        Range("b2") = "Monday"
        Range("c2") = "Tuesday"
        Range("d2") = "Wednesday"
        Range("e2") = "Thursday"
        Range("f2") = "Friday"
        Range("g2") = "Saturday"
        With Range("a3:g8")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            .Font.Size = 18
            .Font.Bold = True
            .RowHeight = 21
        End With
        Range("a1").Value = Application.Text(MyInput, "mmmm yyyy")
        DayofWeek = Weekday(StartDay)
        CurYear = Year(StartDay)
        CurMonth = Month(StartDay)
        FinalDay = DateSerial(CurYear, CurMonth + 1, 1)
        Select Case DayofWeek
        Case 1
            Range("a3").Value = 1
        Case 2
            Range("b3").Value = 1
        Case 3
            Range("c3").Value = 1
        Case 4
            Range("d3").Value = 1
        Case 5
            Range("e3").Value = 1
        Case 6
            Range("f3").Value = 1
        Case 7
            Range("g3").Value = 1
        End Select
        For Each cell In Range("a3:g8")
            RowCell = cell.Row
            ColCell = cell.Column
            If cell.Column = 1 And cell.Row = 3 Then
            ElseIf cell.Column <> 1 Then
                If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value >= 1 Then
                    cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value + 1
                    If cell.Value > (FinalDay - StartDay) Then
                        cell.Value = ""
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf cell.Row > 3 And cell.Column = 1 Then
                cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 6).Value + 1
                If cell.Value > (FinalDay - StartDay) Then
                    cell.Value = ""
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        For x = 0 To 5
            Range("A4").Offset(x * 2, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            With Range("A4:G4").Offset(x * 2, 0)
                .RowHeight = 65
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                .WrapText = True
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Font.Bold = False
                .Locked = False
            End With
            With Range("A3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, _
                                                     7).Borders(xlLeft)
                .Weight = xlThick
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
            With Range("A3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, _
                                                     7).Borders(xlRight)
                .Weight = xlThick
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
            Range("A3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, 7).BorderAround _
                    Weight:=xlThick, ColorIndex:=xlAutomatic
        Next
        If Range("A13").Value = "" Then Range("A13").Offset(0, 0) _
           .Resize(2, 8).EntireRow.Delete
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
                            Scenarios:=True
        ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub

        start_date.ListIndex = start_date.ListIndex + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

I tried checking if the numbers for the `start_date.ListIndex` and `end_date.ListIndex` output the correct selected values from the combobox, and they worked well.

It does not output anything, even the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to consider:

1-This line is stopping execution from the get go. If start date is smaller than end date then this condition is true and will never enter the loop.

```
Do Until start_date.ListIndex <= end_date.ListIndex
```

I think you should use Do..While instead

```
Do While start_date.ListIndex <= end_date.ListIndex
```

2-This line gives error, I think you are looking to set the Value, not the NumberFormat

```
Range("a1").NumberFormat = ArrayTwo(start_date.ListIndex)
```

3-This line is exiting your loop after one iteration, comment it out

```
Exit Sub
```

4-You are adding two sheets each time with these lines, since you're not using that sheet as a reference (which you should), you can comment out the first line

```
Set wsArrayOne(start_date.ListIndex) = Sheets.Add
Sheets.Add.Name = strArrayOne(start_date.ListIndex)
```

a better way would be to declare a worksheet variable and then use that as your reference throughout (if you don't bind the cell manipulation calls to a sheet, they will happen on whatever the active sheet is at the time, which is OK in this case, but will get you into trouble later on if you are working with multiple sheets at a time. This would be better

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws=Sheets.Add
ws.name=strArrayOne(start_date.ListIndex)
'then bind your cell manuipulations to the worksheet variable like this

ws.Range("a1:g14").Clear
```

Other things to consider are when the user does the unexpected, like picks May to February..the loop will not run, but you could give the user a message saying the start date has to be smaller than the end date. Also, get in the habit of adding error handling to your code, if coding becomes more than a school project then error handling is essential and its best to pick it up early! Good luck!

Comment: Tham totally makes sense ! I changed my code according to your post, and now it work perfectly ! But i have a question, why the new spreadsheets are added to the left of the existing worksheets?   
For example: If i select start day: Mach and end date May, all my spreadsheets are in this order: May April March, but should be in this order: March April May

Comment: add this line after you add the sheet    `ws.Move After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`